# I have one component that is used on every page of my application. How do I declare it so it can be used globally?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a component HeroLogoComponent which is used within the header element of every page on my app. It is declared in app.module as:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  MyApp,
  HeroLogoComponent,
], ...
```

From reading the angular.io documentation, I understand that this should allow the selector `<hero-logo>` to be used in every other PageComponent. However, when I add it to any other page, I get the error

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'logo' is not a known element`

When I change PageComponentModule to include `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` the application loads but the component only displays in the HTML as an empty

```
<hero-logo><hero-logo>
```

with none of the template elements inside. I'd rather declare/import this component once to be used across the app than in every single PageComponentModule. Is there a way to do this so it can be referenced globally?

Thanks!

EDIT:

So in app.module.ts, the bootstrap is IonicApp since it is an ionic generated project.

```
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
```

Are components declared in the bootstrap globally available? And if so, how would I declare it from IonicApp?

Comment: Declare it in the `home` component

Comment: Should I declare the component itself in HomePageModule declarations or declare the module as an import of that module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this code below, the `HeroLogoComponent` will available to every component declared within the *same* declarations array.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  MyApp,
  HeroLogoComponent,
], ...
```

If you have multiple Angular modules and want it accessible to every component in every Angular module, put it in a shared module as Aravind recommended. Then ensure the shared module is imported into every Angular module you define that has components that needs it.

To find out more information, check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntJ-P-Cvo7o&t=6s

Comment: Thanks! The YouTube video helped a lot with this problem and with understanding how ngModules should interact with each other. A++ definitely check it out if you stumbled upon this question, it'll save you tons of time down the line!

Answer (score 1):

Have it in the shared module

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HeroLogoComponent,
    ], 
    exports: [
        HeroLogoComponent,
    ]
```

Import the `SharedModule` across your different modules

Comment: Ok I have it declared and exported from HeroLogoComponentModule. The only way to have it available to a page is to import it to that page's @NgModule?